# Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: ios, react-native

I have written this piece of code to build a simple react native UI

```
'use strict';
 var React = require('react-native');
 var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
  text : {
    color : 'black',
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    fontSize : 30,
    margin : 80
  }
});
class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component() {
  render() {
     return React.createElement(React.text,{style : styles.text},"Hello World");
  }
}
React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder',function(){ return PropertyFinderApp});
```

I am getting error "Super expression must either be null or a function"

I have already tried installing the latest version of react but I am still unable to solve it!

Comment: React.text should be React.Text

Answer (score 1):

What's causing your error is the `React.Component()` which should be without the parentheses `React.Component`. When you fix that you will get another error from the use of lowercase `React.text` which should be `React.Text`.